# Cache Files: How do you protect them, if they must have write permissions?

Tags: php, security, caching, encryption, acl

I use a simple Cache library I wrote, which saves the data I want to have cached, into files under /var/www/my_site/cache/

This directory has read/write permission for everyone, so the apache process, executed by the user apache, can CRUD cache files.

But then I thought that caching sensitive data this way, wasn't secure, due to the read/write permissions. Suppose I have a complicated ACL system, and I cache the permissions for each user, to have them calculated only once. An attacker could edit the corresponding cache file to grant himself full access to the website.

The only solution I can think of is to encrypt the cache files, but this will slow things down (using cache would still be faster than not using it, but still..)

Any ideas?

Comment: Encrypting the cache files would only add another stage of "security" to be bypassed. If someone can break in far enough to get to the cache files and edit them, they can certainly get at your code and read out the keys and encryption method.

Comment: @Marc B thanks for noticing that.

Comment: That's not to say that more security isn't bad, but you have to balance the hassle in granting legitimate access v.s. the likelihood of someone wanting to break in v.s. the cost of handling that breakin. If it takes you 10 years and $10 million to develop the security model and costs X more in cpu and Y more in memory, and in the end only costs you $0.01 to clean, the attacker's won already. You don't store $100 in a safe that costs $50 to crack.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give read/write permissions only to Apache, not everyone.

Comment: Okay. But anyway, an attacker that manages to execute a php script, would be able to modify those files. What can I do about that?

Comment: Then you need to make your website secure.

Comment: I do. But we try to double-secure things when possible. That's why we hash passwords, for example.